# Cherry pick or selective merge from dev branch to prod

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, git-cherry-pick

I have deployed Azure Data Factory pipelines and associated components to adf_publish branch in Azure Devops. Now I want to deploy those changes to the Prod branch, but the problem is that the Prod branch and adf_publish are not in sync. When I try to create a pull request I get 100 files and 100+ commits will be merged message which is not what I want. I want to merge only 1 Data Factory pipeline which was newly created and associated datasets (8) and Linked Service(1).
I tried the cherry pick method from the adf_publish branch but it still takes everything that is missing from Prod Branch. Is there an easy way to accomplish this either through the Azure Devops UI or through Visual Studio Code.

As per the screenshot below I see + next to multiple pipelines which indicates that they are not present in Prod branch, I just want to merge 1 pipeline and leave all the rest in adf_publish.

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. I have tried multiple things but nothing is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ADF_Publish branch will generate ARM templates for deployment automatically. Those templates you will be selecting as part of your release pipeline to perform deployment.

So, after merging ARM templates from ADF_Publish branch to another branch, if you are using same ARM template files from another branch to release deployment then it should work.

If the change(s) you seek aren't in separate commits, break the commit into individual commits using the approach outlined [here](http://plasmasturm.org/log/530/). You use git rebase -i to obtain the original commit to modify, then git reset HEAD to selectively rollback changes, and finally git commit to commit that part as a new commit in the history.

Another useful technique is described in [Red Hat Magazine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130727101330/http://magazine.redhat.com:80/2008/05/02/shipping-quality-code-with-git/%20for%20more%20related%20details.), where they use git add —patch or maybe git add —interactive to add just sections of a hunk if you wish to separate various changes to specific files (search in that page for "split").

After splitting the modifications, you may now pick and choose which ones you wish.